# Not able to login into Docker through AWS CLI

Tags: docker, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

I am trying to push one docker image to my AWS ECR, but i am getting this error during login

Command I used:

```
aws ecr-public get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin public.ecr.aws/xxxxxx
```

Error

```
failed to get console mode for stdin: The handle is invalid.
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `The stub received bad data.
```

Comment: Did you configure the aws credentials?

```aws configure```

Comment: I did configure my aws ci

Comment: *use which os?*

Answer (score 0):

Split the piped command up into it's separate commands:

First run `aws ecr-public get-login-password --region us-east-1` and see the password it outputs.

Then run the second command, but pass it the password as an argument: `docker login --username AWS --password <password-output-from-previous-command> public.ecr.aws/xxxxxx`

This will help you isolate the error you are encountering, and possibly get completely past it.

---

If you can, I highly recommend using [AWS ECR Credentials Helper](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your command seems to be correct, However can you help me understand which OS are you using second what is the AWS CLI version that you are using in order to isolate the issue.

Command `aws ecr get-login-password --region region | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com`

Here is the official help whitepaper - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-push-ecr-image.html

Comment: answer posts are not for asking questions. which part of this post answers the question?

Comment: @starball The second half answers the post! I hope you have read the complete answer